# Does first() return a collection in Laravel? Can i access the properties directly without using toArray()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Fairly new to Laravel and having trouble getting a user's first name. The first and last name are stored in a separate table called superusers. I have a users model containing:

```
public function Superuser(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Superuser');
}

public function getFirstName(){
    if ($this->usertype == 1) {
        return $this->Superuser->first_name;
        }
}
```

and a SuperUser model

```
public function User(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

The superusers table contains columns id, first_name, last_name, mobile, timestamps.

When I call `Auth::user()->getFirstName()` in my blade template I get nothing but if I remove the `->first_name` from the getFirstName method it does return the right object from the table.

I can make this work by returning an array in the method and returning $superuser['first_name'] but I have a feeling I am misunderstanding something fundamental that I should probably figure out!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

first() returns a single model, not a collection.  I think that your code should work except that maybe the Superuser function (not class) should be all lower case. I have used this construct many times before and not seen this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the answer above helped but as it turns out I had a `public $first_name` in my Superuser model which seemed to be breaking it.

Thanks